# How to build App to run for both ios 7 and ios 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I'm working on project that running fine for ios 7. I want this project for ios 7 and ios 8 both.
I'm using xcode 6 beta 2 for ios 8, I'm using location services in this project and I've made appropriate change in code and working fine for ios 8.

So if I run my project from xcode 5 then it's working fine for ios7, If I run project from xcode 6 beta 2 then it's working fine for ios 8.

My Question is : When I set deployment target 7.0 from xcode 6 beta 2 and build then it's working for ios8 but not working for ios7. It should run in both. :(

Issue in ios7 is not calling webservice delegate methods. I'm using HttpRequest for calling service.

Can Anyone suggest me what to do for using application in ios7 and ios8 both ?

Any Help Will be Appreciated. Thank you!

Code : xcode objective-c

Device : iphone

Functionality : location services,Json Webservice.

Comment: Why are you still using a beta version of Xcode?

Comment: Upgrade to Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: @dandan78,rebello95 Yeah, I Though same thing and xcode 6.0.1 is downloading right now. thanks for suggestions. Is that makes difference. I think it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using XCode 6 beta 2 when XCode 6.0.1 is already out? Download it and try with that, things might work as expected!

Betas are called "beta" for a reason. Try to get the latest stable version and see if you notice any change. It should work for both iOS versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have downloaded xcode 6.0.1 and it's still creating problems with ios8, So I'm debugging app and trying to found solution.